# Вывести только уникальные значения в foreach

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

Есть код вывода массива значений страницы. Вывод нужно сделать по дополнительному полю.

```
<option>Все группы</option>
  {if count($pages) > 0}
    {foreach $pages as $page}
  <option value="{$page.field_ngr}">{$page.field_ngr}</option>
  {/foreach}
```

как можно отсортировать $page.field_ngr чтоб выводились только уникальные значения?

Comment: В коде непонятного шаблонизатора - не знаю, но на PHP это было бы так: `$pages = array_combine(array_column($pages, 'field_ngr'), $pages);` скорее всего подобную операцию надо сделать в контроллере а не в виде. Может быть можно и в шаблонизаторе, если вы его назовёте - но я бы порекомендовал отказаться от шаблонизатора вовсе (для новых страниц сайта), иначе будут постоянные вот такие проблемы: что что-либо нелзьзя сделать, или нет информации.

Comment: это imagecms, она сделана на codeinteger

Comment: можно пропустить массив через array_unique?

Comment: Вот найдите там контроллер для вашего вида (код который вы запостили) - и там уже делайте правки **на PHP** - например то, что я запостил. Попробуйте может и шаблонизаторе сработает. `array_unique` будет сравнивать элементы массива полностью - а вам нужен только ключ `field_ngr` как я понял

Answer (score 0):

самое простое решение, если я правильно понял задачу:

```
$pages = [
    1 => ['field_ngr' => 2],
    2 => ['field_ngr' => 2],
    3 => ['field_ngr' => 6],
    4 => ['field_ngr' => 7],
    5 => ['field_ngr' => 8],
    6 => ['field_ngr' => 8],
    7 => ['field_ngr' => 9],
    8 => ['field_ngr' => 9],
];
$result = [];

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    if (!isset($result[$page['field_ngr']])) {
        $result[$page['field_ngr']] = $page;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

это нужно сделать в контроллере или модели, а результат отдать во вьюху